# Can't display user current location Mapbox iOS API

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I want to display user's current location immediately after they open the app. I use Mapbox iOS SDK. But it doesn't work at all. I don't know what's wrong. I can only see an irrelevant map after I open it.

```
import UIKit
import Mapbox
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate 
{

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MGLMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()  
     }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: Location Delegate Methods

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) 
    {
        let location = locations.last
        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .Follow
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        mapView.setCenterCoordinate(center, zoomLevel: 15, animated: true)
        view.addSubview(mapView)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func  locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
    {
        print ("Errors:" + error.localizedDescription)
    }     
}
```

Comment: Do you get promoted to allow location access? Stopping your location updates after the first update is a bad idea too; the first location isn't likely to be very accurate

Comment: so at what point I should stop? I did that because the consideration of user's battery life.

Comment: If you are targeting ios9+'you can use the request location process that will stop when you have an accurate location. If you want to,work on earlier versions then you need to check the horizontalAccuracy property of the location and stop when it is good enough.  The first location you get on a real device will typically be +/- 1000m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue might be the iOS Simulator. When you run an app on the simulator, it doesn't simulate your location until you tell it to. 
If you look at your Xcode, you'll see a navigate button at the bottom.

[image]

Try changing the location to something, and it should show up :)

Comment: Now it shows location. Thank you, very helpful. You know, I am new to programming. I just can't emphasize enough how thankful I am.